# Error with npm run start. code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

Tags: blockchain, javascript, nodejs, npm

```
npm run start

> blockchain-game@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './nodes'
Require stack:
- G:\sem5Project\blockchain_game\node_modules\@webassemblyjs\ast\lib\index.js
- G:\sem5Project\blockchain_game\node_modules\webpack\lib\wasm\WebAssemblyParser.js
- G:\sem5Project\blockchain_game\node_modules\webpack\lib\wasm\WebAssemblyModulesPlugin.js
- G:\sem5Project\blockchain_game\node_modules\webpack\lib\WebpackOptionsApply.js
- G:\sem5Project\blockchain_game\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- G:\sem5Project\blockchain_game\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\sem5Project\blockchain_game\node_modules\@webassemblyjs\ast\lib\index.js:163:14)    
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'G:\\sem5Project\\blockchain_game\\node_modules\\@webassemblyjs\\ast\\lib\\index.js',
    'G:\\sem5Project\\blockchain_game\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\wasm\\WebAssemblyParser.js',
    'G:\\sem5Project\\blockchain_game\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\wasm\\WebAssemblyModulesPlugin.js',
    'G:\\sem5Project\\blockchain_game\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\WebpackOptionsApply.js',
    'G:\\sem5Project\\blockchain_game\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\webpack.js',
    'G:\\sem5Project\\blockchain_game\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to the @webassemblyjs/ast module. It's likely that there's a missing or corrupted module in your project's dependencies.

Here are some steps you can take to resolve the issue:

Clean Node Modules and Reinstall:
Delete the node_modules directory and package-lock.json file:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
```

After that, reinstall the dependencies:

```
npm install
```

If the issue persist, look into the package.json of your project and check the version of @webassemblyjs/ast. You might need to try a different version. You can update or downgrade the package to see if it resolves the problem.